# $(a+\frac{1}{2})^n + (b+ \frac{1}{2})^n$ is an integer for at most finitely many $n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that for any positive integers $a,b$

$(a+\frac{1}{2})^n + (b+ \frac{1}{2})^n$ is an integer for at most finite number of integers $n$.

Here is what I tried ;
I tried to use mathematical induction to prove it, for $n+1$ and I'm stuck here

$(b+\frac{1}{2})^n (1\frac{1}{2} + b) + (a + \frac{1}{2})^n(1\frac{1}{2} + a)$

Comment: Why would you prove that your expression is an integer using mathematical induction when your expression allegedly ceases to produce an integer for some finite $n$?

Comment: you might try something like $(a+\frac{1}{2})^n + (b+ \frac{1}{2})^n = \frac{1}{2^n}((2a+1)^n + (2b+1)^n)$

Comment: @induktio: By induction (on odd $n$) one can look at the highest power of $2$ that divides $(2a+1)^n+(2b+1)^n$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Nice way of thinking about it :)

Answer (score 1):

The question boils down to the following:
$(2a+1)^n+(2b+1)^n$ is divisible by $2^n$ for at most a finite number of integers $n$.
Consider now two cases:

- $n$ is even, then for any odd $k$ we get that $k^2 \equiv 1\mod{4}$. Make a conclusion.
- $n$ is odd. Then we have that $$ (2a+1)^n +(2b+1)^n = (2a+2b+2)(\dots) $$ where we used that $x^n+y^n = (x+y)(x^{n-1}-\dots + y^{n-1})$ for odd $n$. Notice that in the above expression, the term denoted by dots between the brackets will be odd (why? this is not too hard to see). Therefore, if we want to count the factors of $2$, we should only look at $2a+2b+2$. Now conclude.